# Indent and spacing in tables (or: How to do it better?)

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, indentation

I'm using the `tabular` environment in order to properly display my address in the text. But as the following example shows, the first column of the table doesn't align with the main body text. Also note that the spacing between the main body text and the table is not double (if I add `\\` at the end of the line before the table, the spacing will be more than double). What should I do to align the text of the first column with the main body text, and how do I make sure that the spacing between the rows is the same as between the table and the text above it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing

\begin{document}

\noindent{Here is some text illustrating how the text looks outside a table.}

{\noindent\begin{tabular}{l l}
Address: & My department\\
{} & My university\\
{} & My street\\
{} & My city
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have a suspicion that there might be a much better way to accomplish what I intend here than to use the `tabular` environment. I'm therefore also open to suggestions that don't address the question of how to remove the indentation and how to fix the spacing issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppress the extra space between the beginning of the first column and the text (and also for the last column) using `@{}`; for the vertical spacing issue, use `t` as the optional argument for `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\noindent{Here is some text illustrating how the text looks outside a table.}

\noindent\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l l@{}}
Address: & My department\\
{} & My university\\
{} & My street\\
{} & My city
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `tabular` you could also use `tabbing` (no extra horizontal space to eliminate now) with a local redefinition of `\topsep` (to suppress the extra vertical spacing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is some text illustrating how the text looks outside a table.

{\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\begin{tabbing}
Address: \= My department \\
\> My university\\
\> My street\\
\> My city
\end{tabbing}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you can simply put `Address: \= My department \\` instead of repeating the text twice and killing one of them.

Comment: Using ``tabbing`` is surely better than ``tabular``. tohecz is also right in his comment. I notice, however, that some extra spacing is added both before and after the ``tabbing`` environment. Not a big deal, but it would be nice to avoid that too.

Comment: @Sverre Answer updated.

Comment: @tohecz you're right. I've edited my answer.